# How can I read a HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\MyApp key that have been created under a StdUser Level?

Tags: c++, windows, registry, uac

I have a C++ Win32 DLL, called by a application that is running in requestedExecutionLevel of requireAdministrator in Windows7.

How can I read a HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\MyApp key that have been created under a StdUser Level?

This key was automatically created in the HKEY_USERS\_Classes\VirtualStore\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node

I´ve found [this article about it](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/VistaElevator.aspx) but it refers only about running a process with code injection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

You say StdUser application tried to write a setting into `HKLM\Software\MyApp` and ended up writing it to virtualized location `` HKEY_USERS\<UserSID>_Classes\VirtualStore...` ``. To read it you have to know the UserSID; if there are several users, each user may have different data written in that key.

---

Virtualization is turned off for processes which have `requestedExecutionLevel` in their manifest. See [Controlling Registry Virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965884.aspx#controlling_registry_virtualization) section on how you can modify virtualization behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set privilege `TRegistry *reg=new TRegistry(KEY_WOW64_64KEY)`, if you have 64bit OS. If you have 32 bit OS, `reg->OpenKey("Software")` and you automatically redirected to your key, then you could to do operations with this key.